# "Fake bold" in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it posible to "rough up" a `tikzpicture`, just like the `FakeBold` in `fontspec` for text?

To be more precise, I would like every shape and every path in a `tikzpicture` to be a little bit expanded. And thus lines get thicker and the shape gets bigger.

The motivation of this question is that sometimes after drawing a picture and scaling it to be very small, the original "thickness" of this picture would not be enough for the sake of visibility. Changing `line width` seems to be useless in this case. I've also tried to drop shadow with opacity 100%, but cannot get desired result.

Do you have any suggestions?

---

Below is a picture for test.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=1cm/425cm]
\clip (0cm,0cm) rectangle (425cm,425cm);
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 m2925 1100 c419 -36 775 -108 1158 -234 464 -154 1364 -509 2062 -813 545 -238 850 -354 1265 -479 610 -185 1214 -311 1697 -354 198 -18 546 -8 703 20 300 53 560 165 696 298 114 111 154 261 100 377 -83 182 -428 355 -619 311 -37 -8 -39 -7 -35 14 14 94 256 92 447 -4 148 -75 276 -206 307 -314 22 -73 15 -197 -15 -274 -59 -153 -171 -261 -376 -363 -151 -75 -244 -106 -410 -140 -194 -39 -306 -49 -555 -49 -625 0 -1342 132 -2150 396 -351 114 -633 226 -1155 458 -1411 625 -2216 924 -2758 1024 -291 54 -363 60 -702 61 -287 0 -335 -2 -465 -23 -416 -67 -701 -173 -950 -356 -117 -85 -210 -199 -210 -255 0 -36 -22 -71 -45 -71 -31 0 -45 19 -45 62 0 155 267 374 638 522 244 98 496 155 842 189 81 8 464 6 575 -3z}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is changing line width useless? Where is your MWE code?

Comment: @hpekristiansen I've added some sample code, perhaps you could give a try?

Comment: Ok  changing line width for an SVG will obviously not work. It was near impossible to guess that was your problem. I can not personally solve this problem. From where do you have the SVG path? Can that program not output something thicker? Also - you can make almost the same with the TikZ `calligraphy` package.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Actually I've created this with brush in Procreate and then vectorized it, thus if I want something thicker basically I would have to draw them again. The package you mentioned seems interesting, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used `\pgfusepath{stroke}`, you would be able to thicken the strokes with `\pgfsetlinewidth`.  However, you were drawing the outline and filling it in with `\pgfusepath{fill}`.

You can, however, apply affine transformations to the control points, such as rotations, scaling and translations.  In this case, increasing the y-scale and then translating the image to keep it in frame might give you the effect you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=1cm/425cm]
\clip (0cm,0cm) rectangle (425cm,425cm);
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 m2925 1100 c419 -36 775 -108 1158 -234 464 -154 1364 -509 2062 -813 545 -238 850 -354 1265 -479 610 -185 1214 -311 1697 -354 198 -18 546 -8 703 20 300 53 560 165 696 298 114 111 154 261 100 377 -83 182 -428 355 -619 311 -37 -8 -39 -7 -35 14 14 94 256 92 447 -4 148 -75 276 -206 307 -314 22 -73 15 -197 -15 -274 -59 -153 -171 -261 -376 -363 -151 -75 -244 -106 -410 -140 -194 -39 -306 -49 -555 -49 -625 0 -1342 132 -2150 396 -351 114 -633 226 -1155 458 -1411 625 -2216 924 -2758 1024 -291 54 -363 60 -702 61 -287 0 -335 -2 -465 -23 -416 -67 -701 -173 -950 -356 -117 -85 -210 -199 -210 -255 0 -36 -22 -71 -45 -71 -31 0 -45 19 -45 62 0 155 267 374 638 522 244 98 496 155 842 189 81 8 464 6 575 -3z}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=1cm/425cm]
\clip (0cm,0cm) rectangle (425cm,425cm);
\pgftransformyscale{1.5}
\pgftransformyshift{-50cm}
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 m2925 1100 c419 -36 775 -108 1158 -234 464 -154 1364 -509 2062 -813 545 -238 850 -354 1265 -479 610 -185 1214 -311 1697 -354 198 -18 546 -8 703 20 300 53 560 165 696 298 114 111 154 261 100 377 -83 182 -428 355 -619 311 -37 -8 -39 -7 -35 14 14 94 256 92 447 -4 148 -75 276 -206 307 -314 22 -73 15 -197 -15 -274 -59 -153 -171 -261 -376 -363 -151 -75 -244 -106 -410 -140 -194 -39 -306 -49 -555 -49 -625 0 -1342 132 -2150 396 -351 114 -633 226 -1155 458 -1411 625 -2216 924 -2758 1024 -291 54 -363 60 -702 61 -287 0 -335 -2 -465 -23 -416 -67 -701 -173 -950 -356 -117 -85 -210 -199 -210 -255 0 -36 -22 -71 -45 -71 -31 0 -45 19 -45 62 0 155 267 374 638 522 244 98 496 155 842 189 81 8 464 6 575 -3z}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Original image]

[image: Transformed image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of @Davisior, I managed to do the real "fake bold":

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def\pickern{
    \pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 m2925 1100 c419 -36 775 -108 1158 -234 464 -154 1364 -509 2062 -813 545 -238 850 -354 1265 -479 610 -185 1214 -311 1697 -354 198 -18 546 -8 703 20 300 53 560 165 696 298 114 111 154 261 100 377 -83 182 -428 355 -619 311 -37 -8 -39 -7 -35 14 14 94 256 92 447 -4 148 -75 276 -206 307 -314 22 -73 15 -197 -15 -274 -59 -153 -171 -261 -376 -363 -151 -75 -244 -106 -410 -140 -194 -39 -306 -49 -555 -49 -625 0 -1342 132 -2150 396 -351 114 -633 226 -1155 458 -1411 625 -2216 924 -2758 1024 -291 54 -363 60 -702 61 -287 0 -335 -2 -465 -23 -416 -67 -701 -173 -950 -356 -117 -85 -210 -199 -210 -255 0 -36 -22 -71 -45 -71 -31 0 -45 19 -45 62 0 155 267 374 638 522 244 98 496 155 842 189 81 8 464 6 575 -3z}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=10cm/425cm]
\clip (0cm,0cm) rectangle (425cm,425cm);
\foreach \i in {1,...,60}
{
    \pgftransformxshift{cos{(360/60*\i)}*150}
    \pgftransformyshift{sin{(360/60*\i)}*150}
    \pickern
}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It repeats the picture along a circle to make it look bolder.